# Get the right function to send one email to multiple filenames

Tags: php

I have a code that will get the filename ready for email but Im wondering if anyone could help me get the right function to send one email to multiple filenames.

Here is the code i have so far.

```
 <?php    
    SELECT filename FROM feedback;          
    //you fill the $emails with all the names from the file      
    foreach ($filenames as $filename){     
    //splitting the string, and take all the characters before the .pdf     
    $filename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.pdf'))+"@email.ulster.ac.uk";     
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're sending an email to a filename? I'm very confused.

Comment: And you really shouldn't repost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522845/send-an-email-to-multiple-names-from-a-file-and-change-the-ending - if you have an issue with MarkC's answer there, you could ask him to clarify things.

Comment: Yeah sorry i should have explained more, i have a file full of 'filenames' and for each filename i need to take off the .pdf and add @email and then send them an email? im just wonderinf if anyone could help me with the right function?

Comment: You've taken the answer from your previous question, and added it as a new question. I don't see any sign that you're trying to figure this out for yourself. For one thing, the code you've included isn't correct, so you've clearly not tried any debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, whatever you try to by sending emails to an adress built from a filename, just sent it to multiple receivers:

```
mail('user1@foo.bar; user2@foo.bar', 'topic', 'text');
```